# can't figure out how to do Conversions

Tags: c

This is my first post so please be kind. This code is a countdown with seconds minutes, and hours and it works fine if the number stated is between 0 and 60 but if it is over 60 it breaks and I can't figure it out. How to do it? I tried doing it in Case 1 under the first loop but it just breaks my code. Any help would be appreciated

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch,
 * system("pause") or input loop */
void clock(int n) {
    int i;
    int b;
    int c;
    int C;
    int x;
    int s;
    printf("which countdown do you want\n");
    printf("1.seconds\n");
    printf("2.Minutes\n");
    printf("3.Hours\n");
    scanf("%d", &C);

    b = 0;

    switch (C) {
        case 1:
            scanf("%d", &n);

            for (i = n; i >= 0; i--) {
                if (n > 60) {
                    s = n / 60;
                    s + b;
                }

                printf("%02d", c);
                printf(": %02d", b);
                printf(" : %02d\r", i);
                Sleep(1000);

                break;
            }

        case 2:
            scanf("%d", &n);
            n = n - 1;
            for (b = n; b >= 0; b--) {
                for (i = 59; i >= 0; i--) {
                    printf("%02d", c);
                    printf(": %02d", b);
                    printf(" : %02d\r", i);
                    Sleep(1000);
                }
            }
            break;

        case 3:
            scanf("%d", &n);
            n = n - 1;
            for (c = n; c >= 0; b--) {
                for (b = 59; b >= 0; b--) {
                    for (i = 59; i >= 0; i--) {
                        printf("%02d", c);
                        printf(": %02d", b);
                        printf(" : %02d\r", i);
                        Sleep(1000);
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int n;
    clock(n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific than "it breaks". What is the exact input, expected result and actual result? Even more importantly, now would be a good time to learn to debug your own code. Run your program in a debugger and trace it as it runs. Then update your post with what debugging info you find - that is, where do things first start going wrong?

Comment: What value do you think `n` has when you do `clock(n);`? Hint: It has an indeterminate value.

Comment: When I say  it "breaks" it just writes n in place of the seconds and I can write a new n again this time it is for minutes?

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72398249/edit) your post to update it with that info. Please give the *exact* input, expected result and actual result. And how about debugging? Have you done it and what did you find?

Comment: What do you expect this to do ? `s + b;`

Comment: The answers below are good.  I look forward to learning from them tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

there is a lot wrong here

```
        for (i = n; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (n > 60) { <<<=== n never changes so why is this in the loop
                s = n / 60; <<< you never do anything with s
                s + b; <<< this does nothing at all
            }

            printf("%02d", c); <<<<=== c is never given a value
            printf(": %02d", b); <<< nor is b
            printf(" : %02d\r", i);
            Sleep(1000);

            break; <<<< == you only loop once
        }
```

you probably mean

```
        for (i = n; i >= 0; i--) {
             int hrs = i / 3600;
             int rem = i % 3600;
             int mins = rem /60;
             int secs = rem %60;

            printf("%02d", hrs);
            printf(": %02d", mins);
            printf(" : %02d\r", secs);
            Sleep(1000);

        
        }
```

slightly wasteful in that it recalculates everything every second, but is at least simple

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- you do not initialize variable `b` in cases 1 and 2
- you have a `break` in the body of the `for` loop in case 1, causing the count down to stop after 1 second.
- you pass `n` uninitialized to `clock()` which ignores its argument anyway.
- `clock()` is a standard library function, you should use a different name.
- output to `stdout` is buffered by default, you may need to manually flush the pending output with `fflush(stdout);` to ensure proper display very second.
- the loops and conversions are too complicated. You should just compute the number of seconds, iterate on that and display the remaining hours, minutes and seconds with divisions and modulo operations.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

void countdown(void) {
    int C = 1;
    int n = 0;

    printf("which countdown do you want?\n");
    printf("1: seconds\n");
    printf("2: Minutes\n");
    printf("3: Hours\n");

    scanf("%d", &C);

    switch (C) {
      case 1:  // seconds
        scanf("%d", &n);
        break;
      case 2:  // minutes
        scanf("%d", &n);
        n = n * 60;
        break;
      case 3:  // hours
        scanf("%d", &n);
        n = n * 3600;
        break;
      default:
        return;
    }
    for (;;) {
        // display the countdown:  hours  :  minutes  :   seconds
        printf("\r%02d:%02d:%02d", n / 3600, n / 60 % 60, n % 60);
        fflush(stdout);
        if (n-- <= 0)
            break;
        Sleep(1000);
    }
    printf("LIFT OFF!\n");  // https://www.fai.org/news/3-2-1-0%E2%80%A6-lift-launch-apollo-11
}

int main() {
    countdown();
    return 0;
}
```